# Is using Cloudfront for my CDN dodgey?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

We are thinking of using Cloudfront to host our website images/css/js,

I realise the CDN would have excellent uptime,

but what if the public internet DNS goes down temporarily

(as it does sometimes, here in New Zealand we can't access international sites for a brief period), does Cloudfront rely on such a service?,

This would obviously cause the website to show, but it wouldn't be able to get the CDN assets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) in conjunction with CloudFront to get high-availability DNS. It's possible that CloudFront already uses Route 53, since they're both Amazon products, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Looks like it does :) http://aws.amazon.com/route53/#highlights "You can use Route 53 to map domain names to your Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon S3 buckets, Amazon CloudFront distributions, and other AWS resources. "

Comment: I must say, this looks very interesting! I am still not entirely sure I understand it perfectly, whether it would in fact provide a more available system that public DNS, or maybe it should be used as a fail-safe.